# How to count distinct date timestamps and filter entries based on fixed percentage?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
visitor ---  timestamp
abc     ---  2018-02-03 03:24:26
abc     ---  2018-02-03 02:20:20
abc     ---  2018-02-01 15:10:26
abc     ---  2018-01-31 18:24:26
abc     ---  2018-01-30 12:20:20
abc     ---  2018-01-26 10:10:26
def     ---  2018-02-03 03:24:26
def     ---  2018-01-30 12:20:20
def     ---  2018-01-26 10:10:26
```

I am trying to create a query that finds whether visitors `abc`, `def` are loyal.

My though is to have a fixed timeframe of 14 days. The question is how many times does a visitor signed in. In th case of `abc` had made visits in 5 unique days on this 14 days timeframe.

On the other hand, `def` made visits in 3 unique days.

What I want is to filter, let' say, which visitor was at least 30% loyal on this 14 days timeframe. In this example, `abc` is, but `def` is not.

**The problems with the query:**

- it doesn't take into consideraton the distinct(date(timestamp) and it `sums` all the visits including multiple in a day for each visitor
- I don't know how to filter them let's say 30% as mentioned above

---

```
SELECT visitor, Sum(DATE (TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 14 day)
            AND Curdate()) AS last_twoWeeks
FROM behaviour
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= Curdate() - INTERVAL 14 day
GROUP BY visitor
ORDER BY last_twoweeks DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `count(distinct)`.  To get only the "loyal" visitors, you can use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT visitor, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Date(timestamp)) AS days_last_two_weeks
FROM behaviour
WHERE timestamp >= Curdate() - INTERVAL 14 day
GROUP BY visitor
HAVING days_last_two_weeks >= 0.3 * 14
ORDER BY last_twoweeks DESC;
```

Comment: You sir helped me twice today and I learned valuable lessons. Thank you very much